# How do I click a button on a website using Requests in Node JS

Tags: node.js, headless-browser, requestjs

I want to click the test product on this page: https://biscuit-bird.myshopify.com/collections/all

I am trying to go fully request based and not use a headless browser like puppeteer or zombie as I have already done that.

Please let me know how to do this by sending a request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using this lib? https://github.com/request/request

If so, inside a callback function that provides `body` of the page, you can use some lib to parse HTML content, find your link to a test product with CSS selector, and then open the URL stored in `href`.

This snipped worked for me:

```
const request = require('request');
var HTMLParser = require('node-html-parser');


request({
  url:'https://biscuit-bird.myshopify.com/collections/all',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1'
  }
}, function (error, response, body) {

  // parse method returns a root of the generated DOM
  const root = HTMLParser.parse(body)
  
  // similarly to the browser's DOM, you can lookup DOM elements by their selector using method querySelectorAll  
  const links = root.querySelectorAll("a.grid-link")

  const href = links[0].getAttribute('href');

  // @TODO: send another request to the URL defined in `href`
});
```

Comment: this worked great! Just so I know what's happening here, can you explain what the root.querySelectorAll does, and also explain what is supposed to go inside of 'getAttribute('href');'

Comment: @SalvatoreTimpani, please clarify: you mean what's supposed to _after_ getAttribute('href)? Struggling to understand your request. As for root.querySelectorAll - will update my answer with some comments